# Passing a C character string to linux command line

Tags: c, pointers, exec, command-line-arguments

I have a string in my function defined like ..

```
 char *key="anyvalue";
```

Now I use a linux command as ...

```
 $openssl dgst -md5 -hmac "anyvalue" file.txt
```

Now the problem is I need to carry out following task through a C function ..

Here is the code  ...

```
  void func (char *key) {

     char *key_new=key;

     system("openssl -dgst md5 -hmac <got stuck here> file.txt");

  }
```

How could I pass the key value to the portion labled  ??

I did this pretty simply in php. ...

```
   $key="somevalue"

   exec("openssl -dgst md5 -hmac $key file.txt");
```

Is there something similiar avaliable in C ???

If not then Please tell me any other possible way ???

**Limitation :**

The key has to be passed through function .

I can't take it as a C command line argument.

Edit :

I tried with this one ... but first of all I would like to mention that its a small file in a big project and warning being treated as error .. so I need to take care of them also

Here is what I did -

```
    char *sstring=NULL;
    sprintf(sstring, "openssl dgst -md5 -hmac \"%s\"
    -out data3.md5 data3.txt",(char *)key);
    system(sstring);
```

if I won't initialize then here comes the warning ..

```
    gcc -o hmacmd5.so -I.. -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall 
    -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs
    -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\"
    -shared hmacmd5.c ../libsendipaux.a ../libsendipaux.a

    cc1: warnings being treated as errors
    hmacmd5.c: In function ‘xoricv’:
    hmacmd5.c:271:9: error: ‘sstring’ is used uninitialized in this function
    make: *** [hmacmd5.so] Error 1
```

Comment: If the value of `key` is supplied in program input, you may be opening yourself up to security bugs. Consider: what if `key` is `abcdef$(rm -f /etc/passwd)ghijkl` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `sprintf`:

```
int sprintf(char *STR, const char *FORMAT, ...);
```

In your case, you would use it as follows:

```
sprintf(some_allocated_output_string, "openssl -dgst md5 -hmac %s", key);
system(some_allocated_output_string);
```

**EDIT:**

After seeing the code you tried, I can see I didn't provide you a complete answer.

You have two choices here (assume that `STRING_SIZE` below is some `#defined` size, like 300 or something):

1) use a preallocated buffer:

```
char sstring[STRING_SIZE];
sprintf(sstring, "openssl -dgst md5 -hmac \"%s\" -out data3.md5 data3.txt",(char *)key);
system(sstring);
```

2) use malloc/free:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//blah blah blah
char *sstring=NULL;
//blah blah blah
sstring = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
sprintf(sstring, "openssl -dgst md5 -hmac \"%s\" -out data3.md5 data3.txt",(char *)key);
system(sstring);
free(sstring);
```

I would suggest the first approach.  Along with this, I would highly suggest taking care to use @pmg's suggestion of `snprintf`, if your compiler supports it.  This would look like this:

```
char sstring[STRING_SIZE];
int result = 0;
result = snprintf(sstring, STRING_SIZE, "openssl -dgst md5 -hmac \"%s\" -out data3.md5 data3.txt",(char *)key);
// Perform a check on result here, in case you ran out of space.
// If result > STRING_SIZE, you need to try a larger buffer.
system(sstring);
```

Comment: +1; even better, if the OP has a C99 compiler, is [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html).

Comment: I *strongly* agree.  Safer is better, especially when it comes to buffers.  `sprintf` just came to the fingers first... old habits and all that ;^)

Comment: @UditGupta Can you post the code you tried, and I'll see if I can steer you in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You should learn to use the openssl API instead of invoking command lines.

Failing that, you need to use `system`, not fork.

Comment: +1 for redirecting to the [OpenSSL API](http://www.opensslbook.com/api/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the character " inside a C string, you could write it with \"

So, you write

```
system("openssl dgst -md5 -hmac \"key\" file.txt");
```

If you key is not a constant, you should use `snprintf`

Something like this:

```
char buffer[/*enough size*/];
snprintf(buffer, /*the size*/, "openssl dgst -md5 -hmac \"%s\" file.txt", key);
```

And after

```
system(buffer);
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. How does he get the value of `key` into the string at all, let alone quoted?

Comment: string is variable .... everytime I invoke the function a new key value is passed and as I think what you have suggested is a fixed key value "key"

Comment: @UditGupta I edited the post. However, you still need to remember to use \" in the string

Comment: but how will I execute system command then ???? I need to provide this whole string as a input to `system ` command and if I use something like `char *str` in place of this whole srting then how wud i add this key there ??

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 void func (char *key) {

     char *cmd = "openssl -dgst md5 -hmac ";
     char *fullmsg = _malloc( strlen(key) + strlen(cmd) );
     if (fullmsg != NULL) {
       sprintf_s( fullmsg, sizeof(fullmsg), "%s%s", cmd, key );
       system( fullmsg );
       free( fullmsg );
     } // else out of memory

  }
```

Comment: Ah, that may only be available in Microsoft's C compiler.  Use sprintf() instead then, just ensure you don't overrun the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
void func(char * key)
{
    char cmd[255] = "openssl dgst -md5 -hmac ";
    assert(sizeof cmd > strlen(cmd) + strlen(key));
    strcpy(cmd, key);
    system(cmd);
}
```